# How to jump directly to a Gmail label in "Move to"?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, keyboard-shortcuts

In Gmail, I have among my labels **Work** and **co-workers** (both have further sub-labels underneath).

When I want to *file* a message under **work**, I type "work" in the *Move to* box, but then I need to *scroll down* past all the **co-workers**:

[image]

Is there a way to type something in *Move to* that will take me *directly* to **Work**?

Comment: You said "Work" has sub-labels? Wouldn't `work/` suffice?

Comment: Maybe bypass the problem altogether and change `co-workers` to something like `colleagues`.

Comment: Typing `work/`, _@Al E._, jumps to the first sub-label of `work`, not to `work` itself.

Comment: Sure, but then you've only got to up-arrow one time. It's not a perfect solution; it's a partial workaround. That's why I left it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

What I do is pre-end one highly used label with "_" so it sorts to the TOP of the list for each access. You could do that with 8 or so labels to make them easy, everything else would need scrolling to find.